# How can i install bcrypt on Flask project?

Tags: python, flask, pip, bcrypt

it's a new Flask project with requirement.txt:

- flask
- flask_pymongo
- flask_pymongo
- flask_cors
- pyjwt
- Flask-JWT-Extended
- bcrypt

When i run `pip install requirement.txt` or `pip install bcrypt` here what i have

[pip install bcrypt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W09Nd.png)

Any solution please ?

Comment: First, [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. Second, did you read the error message? It tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: Please read the error message! It contains instructions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're bumping up against is `bcrypt` has C++ / binary dependencies.

On some platforms it is very easy to obtain a compiler toolchain,
such as clang or gcc, and suitable header files.
On yours it might be somewhat inconvenient to obtain e.g. Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0.
Pip is very good at handling python deps.
Less so for complex binary deps.
**Conda** was designed to offer good solutions to exactly this problem.

Get it from: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install

Discard requirements.txt in favor of a new environment.yml file:

```
name: my-project  # or feel free to invent a better name :)

channels:
- conda-forge

dependencies:
- bcrypt
- flask
- flask-cors
- flask-jwt-extended
- flask-pymongo
- pip
- pyjwt
- python >= 3.9.9
```

Run `conda env update`:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

Downloading and Extracting ...
done
#
# To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate my-project
```

That "activate" command will alter your `PATH`,
giving you a brand new python interpreter which has all needed libraries
available to it. Have fun with your new project!